# Filter text in vim

Tags: vim

I have text in vim editor that I would like to be filtered. I need to show only lines that contains string `com:`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following pattern in `vim`:

```
:g/com:
```

---

More info can be found in [vim Power of g](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g)

> **Brief explanation of :g**
>
> ```
> :[range]g/pattern/cmd
> ```
>
> This acts on the specified [range] (default whole file), by executing
>   the Ex command cmd for each line matching pattern (an Ex command is
>   one starting with a colon such as :d for delete). Before executing
>   cmd, "." is set to the current line.

Check [vim Power of g](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g) for more info.